# Time Complexity of permutation function Should be T((n!)^2)?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, permutation, backtracking

**Problem**

Given an array of nums of distinct integers, return all the possible permutations.

For example, `[1,2,3]` would have the following permutations:

```
[ [1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,1,2], [3,2,1] ].
```

This is my Javascript implementation, similar to the standard solution for this problem.

I found many places saying this time complexity is to be T(n*n!). But as I understand it should be T((n!)^2). Again I could be wrong.

**JavaScript solution**

```js
var permute = function(nums) {
    if(nums.length === 0) return [];
    if(nums.length ===1) {
        return [[...nums]]; 
    }
    
    let results = [];
    const len = nums.length;
    for (let i=0; i<len; i++) {
        // eg: [1,2,3,4]
        const temp = nums[i]; 
        nums[i] = nums[len-1]; 
        nums[len-1] = temp; // [4,2,3,1]
        const n = nums.pop(); // [4,2,3]
        const prems = permute(nums);
        prems.forEach(perm => perm.push(n));
        results = results.concat(prems); 
        nums.push(nums[i]) // [4,2,3,4]
        nums[i] = temp; // [1,2,3,4]
    }
    
    return results;
};
```

Here is how I got the answer as  T((n!)^2)

So for the outer, 1st iteration:

- Each iteration will do a recursive call with n-1 items array
- Then the results, which will be all permutations with n-1 items will be size (n-1)!
- So we have to loop through (n-1)! items to append the popped element.

For n iterations: so for the first recursive call, this will happen n times (the outer loop is going from 0 to n)

So, for the first recursive call T-(n*(n-1)!)

Since the recursion tree size is n!

The final time complexity should be - T(n!*n*(n-1)!) = T((n!)^2).

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is like this:

For the outer loop, n iterations and for permutation n!  Therefore, the time complexity of this algorithm is factorial time, which I think  Σ((n-i) * T(n-i)) -> O(n*n!) is your answer

i from 0 to n